# nextjs params not available during build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using nextjs 13 with experimental app directory. My app uses dynamic routing like so:

```
https://app.domain/[itemid]/[slug]
```

In my **[slug]** directory, if I create **pages.jsx**, a server site route, with the following:

```
export default async function pageComponent ({ params, ...props }) {

    console.log('params': params);
    const data = await afunction(params.itemid);
    ...
```

The app works as expected when I run as *dev*. A url such as:

```
https://app.domain/44/pagetitle
```

Outputs `params.itemid = '44'` and `params.slug = 'pagetitle'` in the console, as I expected.

### Problem

I can't build the app for production. If I run `npm run build`, it attempts to compile **page.jsx** and finds that **afunction** on **pageComponent** is undefined as it had no `params.itemid`. A user never targeted a specific url, so no params were generated when it's building. The params come from dynamic values set in a growing database. The various values in the database may be edited so I don't want an entirely static page.

### Research

Based on the [documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes), I'm unsure of how else I'm supposed to handle this. I feel I'm missing a step here but I don't feel I need to `generateStaticParams` but perhaps I'm wrong on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation, the solution was to add a `generateStaticParams` function, after all. There is a light reference to it in the documentation, under dynamic segments, which I read as an optional preference. Although I wasn't interested (yet) in having static pages created at build time, I was unable to get params working at all without using it, once building and using server side components.

For my use case, I attempted to create a single static page, using it:

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {

    const staticParams = [
        { 
            itemid: '4214', 
            slug: 'apagetitle'
        }
    ]
    return staticParams;
}
```

Which allowed the app to build successfully. Note, this was just for testing purposes and trying to better understand the issue. From the examples, this is intended to generate static pages for entire, or large sections of a database and the examples in the documentation illustrate this fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is very late, but in case others are running into this with the app directory and *a custom server*, the root of my problem was the rendering URL at the app.render() level. So I went from this:

```
server.get('/activities/:slug', async (req, res) => {
  app.render(req, res, `/activities/[slug]`);
});
```

to this:

```
server.get('/activities/:slug', async (req, res) => {
  app.render(req, res, `/activities/${req.params.slug}`);
});
```

and then the params were filled out correctly.